# Put animated prefab as image in button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I created an animated prefab and want to use it as image in button. Is this possible? If not what can I do to insert an animated image in button.

Comment: So...you want to use it. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @Draco18s Yes I want to use it and tried using it. I drag the prefab to image of button but it doesn't allow this.

Comment: I don't understand your goal .. the prefab is animated how? Is it a gif or something like that? Prefab usually refers to a `GameObject` .. which can't be assigned to a `Sprite` field of an image obviously ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about showing an animated 3D prefab on top of your button.

If you have a 3D prefab and want it to be rendered on top of a button, you need to setup a separate render chain.
In essence you add a camera, that renders your object to a RenderTexture. Then you use this RenderTexture as source for an Image component on top of your button.

The critical part is setting up the camera and prefab, so that it doesn't render the whole scene, and isn't visible from whithin the scene.
There are many ways to do that, but I think the easiest way is to place the prefab and camera far away from the rest so that they are outside the view range of the main camera.
Just make sure the camera sees the prefab (and only the prefab) and has the render texture setup as render target.

Comment: That's complicated. I'll just convert my spritesheet to gif

Comment: You never mentioned a spritesheet. A spritesheet is not a prefab. If you already have the sprites, converting them to a gif or video is indeed much easier (and more performant).